# Why doesn't the lock lock?

Tags: c++11, locking, mutex

I have this minimal code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex themutex;

void f1()
{ 
  std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> local_mutex(themutex);
  std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}

void f2()
{
  std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> local_mutex(themutex);
  std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
  f1();
  std::cout << "5" << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
  f2();
  return 0;
}
```

I compile and run with

```
g++ -std=c++11 test_mutex.cc -o test_mutex && ./test_mutex
```

and I get this output:

```
3
4
1
2
5
```

Why?

I expect the program to lock after printing "1" and never to return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 30.4.1 ("Mutex requirements"):

> The expression `m.lock()` shall be well-formed and have the following semantics:
>
> *Requires:* If `m` is of type `std::mutex` or `std::timed_mutex`, the calling thread does not own the mutex.

You're violating the requirements, and so you cannot expect any behaviour guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: thanks. just to make sure I understand: I, i.e. the programmer, have to make sure that I only try to call lock, resp. create a local lock, at most once per thread. Correct?

Comment: @steffen: Yes. If that's not feasible, you can use an `std::recursive_mutex`.